# CGBitmapContextCreate stopped working for iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-graphics

So this piece of code used to work for iOS 8 but stopped working for iOS 9

```
let bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage)
let colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage)
let bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(cgImage)
let context =
    CGBitmapContextCreate(
        nil, newPixelWidth, newPixelHeight, bitsPerComponent, 0, colorSpace,
        bitmapInfo.rawValue)
```

And the CoreGraphics's explanation is:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination:
    8 integer bits/component;
    32 bits/pixel;
    RGB color space model; kCGImageAlphaLast;
    2400 bytes/row.
Valid parameters for RGB color space model are:
    16  bits per pixel,      5  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    128 bits per pixel,      32 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    128 bits per pixel,      32 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast |kCGBitmapFloatComponents
```

But `newPixelWidth` is 600 and 600*4 = 2400. What's the deal here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but haven't you given your own answer?

```
32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
```

None of those are `kCGImageAlphaLast`, so I would assume that's the issue.

Comment: I don't see how not pre-multiplying the alpha will affect the size of context in any way, but it is still a good point. Trouble is, OP is passing in the bitmap info that Core Graphics is generating *itself* for the image (along with the other parameters). Certainly a weird crash though, I can't spot anything else wrong with OP's code.

Comment: @originaluser2 Look at some of the "Related" questions and answers. Changing the bitmap info value did matter. — Plus, there is a lot more in a CGImageBitmapInfo than just the alpha, so maybe the OP is mistreating this value somehow. As I said, I'm no expert on this, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @matt You're right. Passing `CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue` as the last argument to `CGBitmapContextCreate` does work. So I reckon there's no coherent way to resize a valid arbitrary CG image with the latest iOS/SDK (or maybe it's been like this for ages). Thank you for your help. And for your most awesomest books too.

Comment: @matt after some further research (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGImageAlphaInfo) & [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB)), it appears that Quartz *only* supports pre-multiplied alpha formats for images. So I guess OP's code will work fine, but he just needs to be using a supported format for his input image.